# how to show $F=\{(a+2b+3c,a-b,-3a+b-2c,2b+2c),\}$ is a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

how to show $F=\{(a+2b+3c,a-b,-3a+b-2c,2b+2c),\}$ is a subspace? i understand closed subspace should be closed under addition and scalar multiplication

Comment: What are $a,b,c$?

Comment: think easy, they must be real numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the image of **R**$^3$ under the linear transformation described by your formula. So it is a subspace. To see it explicitly take two vectors of the form you described and see that sums of two vectors in that form is again in that form, and so is any scalar multiple.

Answer (score 0):

$(a+2b+3c,a-b,-3a+b-2c,2b+2c)=a(1,1,0)+b(2,-1,2)+c(3,0,2)$ 
Let be $u=(1,1,0),v=(2,-1,2),w=(3,0,2)$ then you have to prove that $u,v,w$ are $\textbf{l.i}$ you can do the determinant of the matrix $[u,v,w]$ where every $u,v,w$ are "column vectors" and show that this is $\neq0$